# Скрыть GET с помощью .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, get

Видно директория: `http:/site.ru/page/?id=1`

На самом деле: `http:/site.ru/page/index.php?id=1`

**Как мне это сделать:** `http:/site.ru/page/1`

Я пробовал через .**htaccess** то выдает **503** то выдает **500** и.т.д ошибки.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page-([^/]*)$ /ilan/?id=$1 [L]
```

Работает но: `http:/site.ru/page-1`не красиво)

```
Если:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /ilan/?id=$1 [L]

Выдает ошибку 500 Internal Server Error
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте содержимое .htaccess чтоле ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /page/?id=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```